# Extracting dates from PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, json

The db is PostgreSQL 9.6.

I'm creating an app that has events, and the user chooses a date / time that he wants to attend.

So, I created the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE public.intervals (
    id            int4 PRIMARY KEY, 
    event_id      int4 NULL,
    date_start    date,
    date_end      date, 
    configuration jsonb DEFAULT '{}',
)
```

I've chosen to put data into a jsonb column instead of creating a new table ( configuration ). There, I put an array of objects, like this:

```
[ { "id": "f53382aa-86b6-e442-8de2-f8c457e5ef11",
    "capacity": 2,
    "duration": 30,
    "end_hour": "12:00",
    "start_hour": "08:00",
    "days_of_week": [ 4, 5 ] },
  { "id": "3d68b5de-7594-fdb9-2848-1190688dd532",
    "capacity": 2,
    "duration": 10,
    "end_hour": "18:00",
    "start_hour": "14:00",
    "days_of_week": [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]
```

Now, I want to extract the dates from this data, and I think I'm getting there, but it's getting too hard.

Am I making a mistake using jsonb to store the configuration?

Here's a fiddle of the table and some example data, in case someone wants to take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/99d30/3/1

Thanks!

Edit:

I think I got it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/99d30/44/0

```
-- select * from intervals;

with days as(
    select
        generate_series(
            date_start,
            date_end,
            '1 day'
        ) as day,
        i.configuration
    from
        intervals i
),
lines as(
    select
        day,
        jsonb_array_elements(configuration) as config,
        ((jsonb_array_elements(configuration)->>'days_of_week')::jsonb) @> ('"' || extract(dow from day)::text || '"')::jsonb as dow_enabled
    from
        days    
)   
  select
    generate_series(
        (
            day::date::text || ' ' ||(
                config ->> 'start_hour'
            )::text
        )::timestamp,
        (
            day::date::text || ' ' ||(
                config ->> 'end_hour'
            )::text
        )::timestamp,
        (
            l.config ->> 'duration' || ' minutes'
        )::interval
    ) as event_date, l.config ->> 'capacity' as capacity
from
    lines l
    where dow_enabled = true
```

It works and it looks fast, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say extract dates can you gives us some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I making a mistake using jsonb to store the configuration?

Yes. You're querying on it. That's usually an indicator to me that you're abusing JSONB.

A few other notes,

1. On your jsonb formatting. I've cleaned it up. Using JSON, `"4"` is not the same as `4`. You should store numbers as numbers and not as strings
2. Your default for configuration is `{}`, but your sample data shows `[{},{}]`. It's bad practice to store some arrays-of-objects, and some objects in the top level. Pick one.